# How can I show that this operator is bounded on $L^2$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, integral-operators

> Consider the integral operator
>
> $$Tf(x) = {\int}_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x - y)}{x - y}f(y)dy$$
>
> How can I show that $T$ is bounded on $L^2$?

I know that bounded means there is a constant $c$ independent of $f$ such that ${\| Tf \| }_{L^2} \leq c \|f\|_{L^2}$ but I do not seem to succeed on solving this.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}
   Tf(x) &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x-y)}{x-y}f(y)dy \\
      &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^{1}e^{is(x-y)}ds f(y)dy \\
      &= \frac{1}{2}\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\int_{-R}^{R}\int_{-1}^{1}e^{is(x-y)}dsf(y)dy \\
      &= \lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^{1}\left(\int_{-R}^{R}e^{-isy}f(y)dy\right) e^{isx}ds \\
      &= \frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{2}\int_{-1}^{1}\hat{f}(s)e^{isx}ds.
\end{align}
The last equality holds because $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-R}^{R}e^{-isy}f(y)dy$ converges in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ to $\hat{f}$ as $R\rightarrow\infty$. Therefore $Tf \in L^2$ and, by the Plancherel Theorem,
$$
               \|Tf\|_2 = \pi\|\hat{f}\chi_{[-1,1]}\|_2 \le \pi \|\hat{f}\|_2 = \pi \|f\|_2.
$$

Answer (score 5):

It's been suggested that this follows from Young's inequality. It does not. One special case of Young is $||f*g||_\infty\le||f||_2||g||_2$ (of course that special case is just Cauchy-Schwarz.) That applies here, but it shows that $||Tf||_\infty\le c||f||_2$, not $||Tf||_2\le c||f||_2$. The case of Young's inequality that *could* show $T$ is bounded on $L^2$ is $||f*g||_2\le||f||_2||g||_1$, but that doesn't apply here, since the function $\sin(t)/t$ is not integrable.

The good news is that it's  clear from Plancherel that $$||f*g||_2\le||f||_2||\hat g||_\infty,$$where $\hat g$ is the Fourier transform. So you only need to show that the Fourier transform of $\sin(t)/t$ is in $L^\infty$, which is true. (See "**Detail**" below...)

(Don't calculate the Fourier transform of $\sin(t)/t$ directly. Instead look in the back of the book: Calculate the Fourier transform of $\chi_{[-1,1]}$ and apply the $L^2$ inversion theorem.)

**Note** I'm not claiming that the Fourier transform of $\chi_{[-1,1]}$ is exactly $\sin(t)/t$. In a context like this it's impossible to say exactly what the Fourier transform of anything is, exactly. The reason is that various authors define the Fourier transform differently, putting the $2\pi$'s in different places. If you calculate the Fourier transform of $\chi_{[-1,1]}$ by whatever definition you're using you'll get something sort of like $\sin(t)/t$, close enough to let you figure out a $\phi\in L^\infty$ such that $\hat\phi(t)=\sin(t)/t$. So Plancherel implies that the Fourier transform of $\sin(t)/t$ is bounded.

$\newcommand{\ft}{\mathcal F}$
$\newcommand{\ift}{\mathcal F^{-1}}$
$\newcommand{\sp}{\mathcal S}$

**Detail:** Why is it that $||f*g||_2\le||f||_2||\hat g||_\infty$ for $f,g\in L^2$? The obvious argument would be this:
$$||f*g||_2=||\widehat{f*g}||_2=||\hat f\hat g||_2\le||\hat f||_2||\hat g||_\infty=||f||_2||\hat g||_\infty.$$

But this raises the question of what $\widehat{f*g}$ *is*, since $f*g$ is not in $L^1$ or $L^2$. (I for one find it amusing that nobody's asked about this, given all the silly objections regarding elementary applications of Plancherel; this spot *is* at least somewhat problematic.) One could avoid the question by showing instead that $f*g=\ift(\hat f\hat g)$; there at least it's clear what everything *means*, because $\hat f\hat g\in L^1$.

But we get a simpler and more elegant argument by interpreting $\widehat{f*g}$ in the sense of tempered distributions. (Two fairly accesible references for the basic theory of tempered distributions would be the relevant chapters in Rudin *Funtional Analysis* and Folland *Real Analysis*.) Just to keep things clear, I'll be using the notation $\ft u$ for the Fourier transform of the tempered distribution $u$, reserving the notation $\hat f$ for $f\in L^1$ or $f\in L^2$. Wee need to show this:

> > $\ft(f*g)=\hat f\hat g$ for $f,g\in L^2$.

Proof: First, if $f,g\in L^1$ then $f*g\in L^1$, and a standard application of Fubini shows that $$\ft(f*g)=\widehat{f*g}=\hat f\hat g.$$

Now suppose $f,g\in L^2$. Choose $f_n,g_n\in L^1\cap L^2$ such that $f_n\to f$ and $g_n\to g$ in $L^2$. Then $f_n*g_n\to f*g$ uniformly. Hence $f_n*g_n\to f*g$ in $\sp'$ (that is, "in the sense of tempered distributions"). Since $\ft$ is continuous on $\sp'$ it follows that $\ft(f_n*g_n)\to\ft( f*g)$ in $\sp'$. Similarly, $\hat f_n\to\hat f$ and $\hat g_n\to\hat g$ in $L^2$, so $\hat f_n\hat g_n\to\hat f\hat g$ in $L^1$ and hence $\hat f_n\hat g_n\to \hat f\hat g$ in $\sp'$. And so we're done: $$\ft(f*g)=\lim\ft(f_n*g_n)=\lim\hat f_n\hat g_n=\hat f\hat g,$$(where $\lim$ denotes convergence in $\sp'$).

Comment: The Fourier Transforms of $\sin t/t$ is not $\chi_{[-1,1]}$. it is not even bounded. the reason is $\sin t /t$ is not integrable so the Fourier transform is not invertible there.

Comment: @GuyFsone For heaven's sake, have you heard of the Plancherel theorem?

Comment: @GuyFsone So tell me, what _is_ the Fourier transform of $\chi_{[-1,1]}$?

Comment: I know the Plancherel as well. I am talking about the Fourrier transform of $\chi_{[-1,1]}$ which is obviously $\sin t/t$. But Can you tell me now what is the Fourrier inverse of $\sin t/t$? Hint: it is obviously not $\chi_{[-1,1]}$. Now have you ever here about the the assumption on invertibility of the FT?

Comment: If the Fourier transform of $\chi_{[-1,1]}$ is $\sin(t)/t$ then it follows from Plancherel that the Fourier transform of $\sin(t)/t$ is $\chi_{[-1,1]}$ (more or less, modulo where we put the $2\pi$ in the definition.) This is clear because both functions are _even_.

Comment: @GuyFsone That's wrong. The Fourier transform is an automorphism on $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$, so $\sin(t)/t \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$. And of course $\sin(t)/t$ is bounded.

Comment: @GuyFsone _Because_ (if we put the $2\pi$'s in the right place in the definition) it's clear from Plancherel that $\mathcal F^2 f(t)=f(-t)$ for $f\in L^2$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich **that is absolutely wrong and completely wrong**. the FT is not invertible for that function. Unless you prove that by computation. Avoid hidding yourselld behind Plancherel which has nothing to do with problem at hand

Comment: @GuyFsone Maybe we shoulldn't call it the Fourier transform. Let's  call it the Plancherel trnasform instead. That operator on $L^2$ that agrees with the Fourier transform on $L^2\cap L^1$. Take $\mathcal F$ to be the Plancherel transform; then it's absolutely and completely true that $\mathcal  F^2 f(t) = f(-t)$ for every $f\in L^2$. Btw people "always" refer to the Plancherel transform as just the "Fourier transform".

Comment: @GuyFsone Proof, in case you haven't got it yet: It's clear from the $L^1$ inversion theorem that $\mathcal F^2f(t)=f(-t)$ for, say, $f$ in the Schwartz space. But $\mathcal F$ and the operator we might informally describe as $f(t)\mapsto f(-t)$ are both bounded on $L^2$, and the Schwartz space is dense in $L^2$.

Comment: @GuyFsone : The $L^2$ Fourier transform can be defined as the $L^2$ limit of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-R}^{R}f(t)e^{-ixt}dt$ as $R\rightarrow\infty$. The resulting transform $\hat{f}$ is a function in $L^2$, and the inverse Fourier transform is similarly defined through the inversion integral. These are inverses of each other in $L^2$; the $L^2$ Fourier transform is unitary on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, as is the inverse Fourier transform.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts it is solved here. thanks. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2546210/prove-that-left-int-xr-frac-sin-xxe-ixtdx-rightc-for-all-r/2546320?noredirect=1#comment5256840_2546320

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Thank you so much for your help. I am just confused at the moment on which answer I should follow. I am not very familiar with this area yet. May you please give me some more details?

Comment: @Georgia Details regarding what step? Hmm. First try reading the chapter on Fourier transforms in Rudin _Real and Complex Analysis_ - that's an excellent introduction at a fairly elementary level.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Details about how to calculate the Fourier transform of ${\chi}_{[-1, 1]}$. Ok. I will start studying from this book. Thanks :-)

Comment: If you know the definition of the Fourier transform then that transform is trivial calculus. Hmm, note this: My copy of Rudin is missing. I'm not certain there's an actual _chapter_ on the FT; if not look in the index for things like "Inversion theorem", or maybe "Fourier inversion theorem", and "Plancherel theorem".

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Thank you. I did found it.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich ok I did calculate the Fourier transform of ${\chi}_[-1, 1]$. And so this implies that the Fourier transform of $\frac{sin(t)}{t}$ is bounded. Are we done? I mean, since we need to show that $\|Tf\|_2 \leq \|f\|_2$ don't we need to add things?(Sorry if my question is silly)

Comment: We're done because $||f*g||_2=||\widehat{f*g}||_2=||\hat f\hat g||_2\le||g||_\infty||f||_2$. Except this raises the question of what $\widehat{f*g}$ might be, since $f*g$ is not in $L^1$ or $L^2$. Regarding that there's a major edit appearing soon...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Thank you so much. Your edits helped me understand how all this work :)