# Prove that : $\left|\int_{|x|<R} \frac{\sin x}{x}e^{-ixt}dx\right|<c$ for all $R>0$ and $t\in \Bbb R$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

This question follow up from a discussion [on this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2545959/how-can-i-show-that-this-operator-is-bounded-on-l2/2546135?noredirect=1#comment5256566_2546135)
Prove that there exists a constant $c>0$ such that for $R>0$ and $t\in \Bbb R$ we have, 
$$\left|\int_{|x|<R} \frac{\sin x}{x}e^{-ixt}dx\right|<c$$

This aim to rpove that the Fourier trnasform of $g: x\mapsto \frac{\sin x}{x}$

Given by 
$$\widehat{g}(t) = \lim_{R\to \infty}\int_{|x|<R} \frac{\sin x}{x}e^{-ixt}dx$$
is bounded. 
Please I would like to see a prove with elementary tools. I mean a prove that can ignore the Fourier analysis here.

Comment: Why would you want to ignore Fourier analysis in a question about a Fourier transform?

Comment: @DanielFischer from  discussion [here][https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2545959/how-can-i-show-that-this-operator-is-bounded-on-l2/2546135?noredirect=1#comment5256566_2546135} it seems to be obvious using plancherel. Although I don't see why?

Comment: Up to constant factors (depending on the normalisation of the Fourier transform), $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ is the Fourier transform of the characteristic function of a bounded interval. By the inversion theorem [for the Fourier transform on $L^2$], the Fourier transform of $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ is [a multiple of] the characteristic function of a bounded interval.

Comment: @DanielFischer that is really the point. I don't want to use that argument. since we don't how the Fourrier transform on $L^2$ look like.  similar can be found here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2535865/how-to-prove-that-left-int-ab-frac-widehatf-xi-xid-xi-right-le-4?rq=1

Comment: The $L^2$ Fourier transform (i) is an isometry on $L^2$ and (ii) agrees with the $L^1$ Fourier transform on $L^2\cap  L^1$. That tells us everything we need to know about what it looks like.

Comment: You say the question follows from that other post. Just for the record, I didn't claim in that other post that this inequality holds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\int_{-R}^R 2\frac{\sin x}{x} e^{-ixt}dx =\int_{-R}^R \int_{-1}^{1}e^{i x u}du e^{-ixt}dx =\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-R}^R  e^{ix(u-t)}dx du = \int_{-1}^1 2\frac{\sin (R(u-t))}{u-t}du=\int_{-1-t}^{1-t} 2\frac{\sin (Rv)}{v}dv=\int_{-R(1+t)}^{R(1-t)} 2\frac{\sin w}{w}dw$$

Thus for $|t| \ne 1$  writing 
$$\int_{-R(1+t)}^{R(1-t)} (...)=  1_{|t|\le 1}\int_{-R(1+t)}^{R(1-t)}(...)+ 1_{|t|>1}\int_{-R(1+t)}^{R(1-t)}(...)$$
we have, 
$$ \lim_{R \to \infty} 1_{|t|>1}\int_{-R(1+t)}^{R(1-t)}(...)=0 $$
Since $|t|>1$ implies $t+1$ and $t-1$ are of the same sign.

On the other hand $|t|<1$ we have, $1+t>0$ and $1-t>0$. whence, 
$$\lim_{R \to \infty} \int_{-R}^R 2\frac{\sin x}{x} e^{-ixt}dx = \lim_{R \to \infty} \int_{-R(1+t)}^{R(1-t)} 2\frac{\sin w}{w}dw \\= 1_{|t|<1}\lim_{R \to \infty} \int_{-R(1+t)}^{R(1-t)} 2\frac{\sin w}{w}dw  = 1_{|t|<1}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 2\frac{\sin w}{w}dw\\ =2\pi1_{|t|<1}$$

The same method works for showing the Fourier inversion theorem for any $f \in L^1,f' \in L^1$ or $f'$ piecewise $L^1$ as here.

Comment: How do you obtain the first equality? also do you directly consider $t>0?$

Comment: By integrating $e^{ixu}$

Comment: Then it should be $e^{-ixu}$

Comment: What did you use in the two last equalities?

Comment: Please do have a nice answer to this ? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2535865/how-to-prove-that-left-int-ab-frac-widehatf-xi-xid-xi-right-le-4?rq=1

Comment: What do you not understand in David's answer ?..

Comment: I think for the last equality it is better to write $$ \int_{-R(1+t)}^{R(1-t)} =  1_{|t|\le 1}\int_{-R(1+t)}^{R(1-t)}+ 1_{|t|>1}\int_{-R(1+t)}^{R(1-t)}$$ and the last term goes to 0 since therein, we have $t+1>0,t-1>0$

Comment: The answer from Davi's is clear to me. may be not well structured

Comment: @reuns If you really want to know, read his comments on my answer. This morning it was _totally and absolutely wrong_. But now it's fine - curious, since it hasn't changed. (I think my favorite is the first comment, where he informs me that the Fourier transform of $\sin(t)/t$ cannot be bounded, because $\sin(t)/t$ is not integrable(!))